# Looking for a way to change all headers and footers on my html/css website at once

Tags: php, html, formatting

I built my website in 2007 using html and css which I learnt from a book. I'm a jeweller and it's used as a portfolio of my work and therefore has lots of photos on it and separate pages with each photo. I have continued to add photos and pages and not made much changes to the overall structure of the website, just copied and pasted the code into each new page and changed the bits I needed to.

But now I want to change the headers and footers of all these pages, and there's hundreds of pages!

After some reading it seems I can use PHP (just finding out about this) to insert headers and footers. Which seems to mean I'd need to edit every page of code anyway, and change all links in the code to .php, which would be the same (or more!) amount of work as just changing the code on every page to be what I want, although will make it easier next time I want to change.... so wondered if there was another way of doing this?

First time asking anything on a web developer forum! As I'm sure you can tell I'm no expert so keep things simple please! My website is [www.islayspalding.co.uk](http://www.islayspalding.co.uk). Many thanks :)

Comment: If all the headers and footers are the same, just download IDE - for example VSCODE and just search for the code you want to change and paste what you want instead? It's one click of a button and it will change it in all your files..

Comment: @verunar thank you so much! I didn't know you could do that :D game changer! Just given it a try and it's working out. Problem solved!